# How to formatting Excel Sheet cells using PHP

Tags: php, excel

Please help me about my doubts on excel and php. I need to do the following process on excel report generation using php

1. to change cell's font styles
2. to change cell's BG color
3. to change cell's width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/). I started using it few days ago and it works very good.

Comment: hi i have used/integrated this...am happy..its a nice tool. thanks for your reference...

Answer (score 2):

With [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/)

- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Features
- http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples

With [PEAR Spreadsheet Excel Writer](http://pear.php.net/package/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer)

- [`Format::setBgColor`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-format.setbgcolor.php) – Sets the cell's background color
- [`Format::setFontFamily`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-format.setfontfamily.php) – Sets the font family.
- [`Worksheet::setColumn`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-worksheet.setcolumn.php) – Set the width of a single column or a range of columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely recommend PHPExcel as well, and it may well supercede the SEW within the PEAR repository